# Displaying index view of a model using twitter-bootstrap tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Im not sure on how to go about displaying an index view of a model using twitter bootstrap tab. I have the following code but its giving me a missing template error. Thanks.

application.html.erb

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
    <p>Home...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    <%= render :template => 'goals#index' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update 1: Showing output of rake routes

```
                  goals GET    /goals(.:format)                  goals#index
                        POST   /goals(.:format)                  goals#create
               new_goal GET    /goals/new(.:format)              goals#new
              edit_goal GET    /goals/:id/edit(.:format)         goals#edit
                   goal GET    /goals/:id(.:format)              goals#show
                        PUT    /goals/:id(.:format)              goals#update
                        DELETE /goals/:id(.:format)              goals#destroy
```

Update 2: Error output

Missing template /goals#index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:

Cheers,
Azren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from what I can see you want to render an index action of a controller, so I would suggest making an index.html.erb in the corresponding view directory, the reason it renders an error about missing the template is because it searches the template in the view>controller_name>action.html.erb

if you are using an action wich isn't CRUD(Create, Read, Update Destroy) then make sure you add it to your routes.rb

```
resource :controller do
  collection do 
    get 'action'
    post 'action', path: "value"
  end
end
```

Comment: It is 1 of the CRUD action which is the index action. I have updated my question above with the output of my routes.

Comment: So when your controller is goals and the action is index you will need to add a file to view>goals>index.html.erb wich is the template. now in this file enter the markup you will need to display in the <%= yield %> method of your application layout.

Comment: I do have that file. and if I go to http://localhost:3000/goals it will display the index view of goals correctly. Anything else that I missed? thanks.

Comment: you might want to set your root :to => "goals#index" in your routes.rb to display the index template right away.